# Upload image via android using php web service not working

Tags: php, android, image

```
<?php
$file_path = "../uploads/";
mkdir("../uploads/");

$file_path = $file_path.basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

echo "File Path =>>>>>>>>>> ".$file_path . "<br />";
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success" . "<br />";
} else{
    echo "fail - ".$file_path . "<br />";
    print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
```

RESULT =

```
     [uploaded_file] => Array
         (
             [name] => test.jpg
             [type] => multipart/form-data
             [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\phpEAF3.tmp
             [error] => 0
             [size] => 283098
         )
 )
```

**FOLDER IS HAVING FULL PERMISSSION, as ERROR 0 is coming i have given full permission to the folder.**

Comment: Are any errors thrown? (Example : from the `move_uploaded_file()` function)?

Comment: Also you can't upload to a relative path, you need to use the absolute path.

Comment: Turn on error reporting -> `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: What value of upload_max_filesize? And can you publish the answer of  move_uploaded_file() function?

Comment: No I am not getting any error. The problem is i am not able to see the file on my server. ERROR REPORTING IS ON as mentioned in the comment

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP: Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php),
**Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.**

Maybe something's wrong when moving the file.

Comment: Yes you are right, but how to detect that moving is not working. Is it related to path, i have full doubt in my path. I have used simple "/" also but then also i am not able to see the file.

Comment: if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) @ this line I am getting fail. So the problem is in moving file but don't know what error its having. Can you guide me how can i print error in moving file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with absolute path url for moving upload file to server location.